# Отдельные классы в проекте

Tags: java, android, классы

на андроиде, написание на Java есть программа калькулятор, которая имеет свои методы для проверки строки на неправильные символы, и последующее их удаление, или фикса, своеобразная проверка на правильность выражения, и проверка будет происходить после каждого нажатия. И соответственно будут постоянно создаваться или экземпляры классов, или будут обращаться методы основного класса к статическим методам другого класса. Что может сказаться на затрате ресурсов телефона. Интересует именно как сильно это влияет на быстроту выполнения методов программы, с много поточностью, без неё. заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если экземпляры классов создаются не в количестве десятков миллионов штук, то проблем быть не должно

Comment: ну и 100 раз обращений и созданий за один клик кнопки не будет. и что значит даже если 1000 созданий  классов не вызовет проблему? раз вы про миллионы говорите. Под проблемой Я подразумеваю естественно долгую реакцию приложения.

Comment: странно переживать, что в объектно-ориентированном языке создаются объекты, по другому оно и не работает  как бы ... единственное о чем стоит волноваться в этом контексте - утечки памяти (не нужные больше классы, которые сборщик мусора по тем или иным причинам не может удалить) - об остальном позаботится сборщик мусора

Comment: ну ясно понятно что для Вас знание фундаментальных вещей даёт ответ на мой вопрос, но что то я вот читаю что такое ооп и другие методы, и ни как не доходит, как будто читаю книгу вижу фигу, лет через 10 может начну разбираться. то есть для меня, в плане теории, нужен пример, аналог, и тогда только начну разбираться. спасибо за ответ.